# Why I am getting error no match for ">>" operator?

Tags: c++

`error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'std::vector<char>')`

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    vector<char> b[n], g[n];
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> b[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        cin >> g[j];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (b[i] == g[j]) {
                b[i - 1] = b[i];
                i++;
                g[j - 1] = g[j];
                j++;
                n = n - 1;
            } else {
                rotate(g.begin(), g.begin() + 1; g.end());
            }
        }
        int k = g.size();
        cout << k;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing `#include <iostream>`. Also, you should never explicitly include `bits/*`, because they're usually compiler specific, and are meant to be included from stdlib files. Each "bit" of the stdlib may not contain what you're looking for

Comment: Note that `vector<char> b[n]` declares an array of `n` `vector<char>` (or would do if variable length arrays were allowed).  I suspect you want `vector<char> b(n)`.

Comment: You'd also need to initialise n before you can use it in the b[n] definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused between `[n]` and `(n)`. Using `vector<char> b[n]` ***tries*** to create an array of vectors while you most probably want a `vector<char>` having `n` elements.

Also you are passing uninitialized `n` to `vector<char>` constructor (wait, it wasn't a constructor in your case, but if you just made a fix keeping my above point in mind then now surely it is :)).

You need to first input `n` and then use it as size. Also, there is a typo in line 22, you've put a `;` in between a call to `rotate` function.

Here is your fixed and improved code: (PS: Try not using `bits/` headers; also better use ranged-based `for` loops instead of traditional ones.)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<char> b(n), g(n);

    for (auto &&i : b)
        cin >> i;
    for (auto &&i : g)
        cin >> i;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            if (b[i] == g[j]) {
                b[i - 1] = b[i]; 
                ++i;
                g[j - 1] = g[j];
                ++j;
                --n;
            } else {
                rotate(g.begin(), g.begin() + 1, g.end());
            }
        }
        cout << g.size() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```